# Arraylist based program

Tags: java, class, arraylist

```
package arrayprogram;
public class ArrayProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) {
            Store watchStore = new Store();
            String wcome = Menu.welcome();
            int opt = Integer.parseInt(wcome);


            switch(opt){
                case 1:
                    watchStore.addWatches();
                    for(;;){
                        String option = InputHelper.getInput("you want to add another watch (Y/N) ?: "); 
                        if ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(option)) {
                            watchStore.addWatches();
                        }else{
                            break;
                        }
                    }    
                case 2:
                    String back = Menu.welcome();
                    int option = Integer.parseInt(back);
                    if(option == 2)
                        watchStore.viewWatch();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    Watch found;
                    found = watchStore.findWatchBySerialNumber(333);
                    System.out.println(found);
                    break;
            }
}

}
```

the above code contains my main method the rest of the class will follow

> Store class

```
package arrayprogram;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Store {

    ArrayList<Watch> watchStore = new ArrayList<>();
    Watch wt = new Watch();

    public void addWatches(){

            String name = InputHelper.getInput("Enter name: ");
            String serial = InputHelper.getInput("Enter serial: ");
            String desc = InputHelper.getInput("Enter description: ");
            String color = InputHelper.getInput("Enter Color: ");
            String price = InputHelper.getInput("Enter price: ");
            String weight = InputHelper.getInput("Enter weight: ");

            double pr = Double.parseDouble(price);
            double wg = Double.parseDouble(weight);
            long sr = Long.parseLong(serial);

            wt.addWatch(name, sr, desc, color, pr, wg); // this is a method inside Watch class that is responsible for adding watch information
            watchStore.add(wt);
    }

    public void viewWatch(){
        for (int i = 0; i<watchStore.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(watchStore.get(i));
        }

    }

    public Watch findWatchBySerialNumber(long serial) {
        for(Watch w : watchStore) {
            if(w.getSerial() == serial) {
                System.out.print("found");
                return w;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("not found");
        return null;
    }

    public void deleteWatch(){
        //the code will follow
    }

    public void averageWatch(){
        //the code will follow
    }

}
```

> InputHelper class

```
package arrayprogram;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputHelper {
    public static String getInput(String prompt){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(prompt);
        System.out.flush();

        try{
            return input.nextLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return "Invalid entry";
        }
    }
}
```

> Menu class

```
package arrayprogram;
public class Menu {

    public static String welcome(){
        return InputHelper.getInput("Welcome our watch store\n"
                    + "1. Add new watch\n"
                    + "2. Delete Watch by serial number\n"
                    + "3. View all watches information\n"
                    + "4. Search watch by serial number\n"
                    + "5. View average weight of available watch\n"
                    + "\n"
                    + "Choice: "
            );


    }


}
```

> finally the above program works a little bit well. but the am having with the above program is that.
>
> 1. i cant be able to search the arraylist for a particular watch object with a matching serial number.
> 2. any suggestion with regards to the above program is welcome. any improvement.

Comment: for part 2 [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) will be a better place

Comment: It would also be great if you tell us what your input is.

Comment: Can you try it like this: ArrayList<Watch> watchStore = new ArrayList<Watch>(); ? Also, we would like to know how is your code failing. What is the input, what do you expect and what is the unexpected output?

Comment: If i am not completly mistaken by that bunch of code then you are allways adding the same instance of `Watch` to your `ArrayList`. You never reinitialze your `wt` variable, which strangly is a class variable. You could try to find your latest Watch in your list, this should be found.

Comment: Too much code, seems unecessary to get the problem. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve And introduce the problem, what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the case but in your `getInput()`, search watch is #4 but in your `switch` it is number 3. Make sure you are entering #3

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Map instead of an ArrayList. Also :

- Use interfaces :

  List watchStore = new ArrayList<>();
  instead of :
  ArrayList watchStore = new ArrayList<>();
- In the Store class your List and your Watch should be private.
- You shouldn't have text in the code, you should use a resource (for example a properties file) to provide the text.
- You shouldn't have anything like "y" or "\n" directly in the code, they should be declared as constants.
- "serial_no" is not a correct Java naming, it should be "serialNo".
- You should use an Enum instead of the value of an integer for options.
- What is the point of addWatch(...) why don't you use the constructor? Why are you modifying the same Watch object over and over and not creating a new object every time? Are you sure your program works?
- You should have Javadoc and comments.

... (that don't stop here, use CheckStyle, PMD and Findbugs to check your code and write unit tests)

Answer (score 0):

I found two major problems in your code:

The first one, your are never repeating your menu call in your code, as far as i could see it. you could do it like this (note that the only thing that i changed is the recursive call of the menu). There might be some other problems in there.
    package arrayprogram;

```
public class ArrayProgram {
    static Store watchStore = new Store();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print();
    }

    private static void print() {

        String wcome = Menu.welcome();
        int opt = Integer.parseInt(wcome);
        switch (opt) {
        case 1:
            watchStore.addWatches();
            for (;;) {
                String option = InputHelper.getInput("you want to add another watch (Y/N) ?: ");
                if ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(option)) {
                    watchStore.addWatches();
                } else {
                    print();
                    break;
                }
            }
        case 2:
            String back = Menu.welcome();
            int option = Integer.parseInt(back);
            if (option == 2)
                watchStore.viewWatch();
            print();
            break;

        case 3:
            Watch found;
            found = watchStore.findWatchBySerialNumber(333);
            System.out.println(found);
            print();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The second major flaw is that you are allways working on the same instance of `Watch`. If you are adding a Watch with the serial number `1` and add another Watch with the serial number `2` then your ArrayList basicly contains the same object twice, filled with the information of your second watch.
This change should be a minor change, just move your class variable `wt` inside the method `addWatches`.

```
public void addWatches(){
    String name = InputHelper.getInput("Enter name: ");
    String serial = InputHelper.getInput("Enter serial: ");
    String desc = InputHelper.getInput("Enter description: ");
    String color = InputHelper.getInput("Enter Color: ");
    String price = InputHelper.getInput("Enter price: ");
    String weight = InputHelper.getInput("Enter weight: ");

    double pr = Double.parseDouble(price);
    double wg = Double.parseDouble(weight);
    long sr = Long.parseLong(serial);

    Watch wt = new Watch();
    wt.addWatch(name, sr, desc, color, pr, wg); // this is a method inside Watch class that is responsible for adding watch information
    watchStore.add(wt);
}
```

Notice that there is still a lot space to improve your project, aswell as it has some more flaws (not matching switch condition against your menu, it only searches for serial number `333`,....)

Comment: how can i then add every instance each time i let user to add watch

Answer (score 0):

You never show the full list of items properly. I can see that it is getting stuck at option 1 as there is no way to exit. I have corrected it here. Please check the code below which removes the use of the for loop. It includes a while loop that runs forever but which shows the correct catalouge everytime.

```
public class ArrayProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
            Store watchStore = new Store();

            while( true )
            {
                String wcome = Menu.welcome();
                int opt = Integer.parseInt(wcome);

                switch(opt){
                    case 1:
                        watchStore.addWatches();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        String back = Menu.welcome();
                        int option = Integer.parseInt(back);
                        if(option == 2)
                            watchStore.viewWatch();
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        Watch found;
                        found = watchStore.findWatchBySerialNumber(17);
                        System.out.println(found);
                        break;
                    case 4: System.exit(0);
                }
            }
}
}
```

Then comes the part where you use a single instance of watch all the time. This only adds trouble. You should be instantiating the watch class everytime. And you have to add it to the array list. The below is the corrected code. Please note that watch store instance is created everytime.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Store 
{
    ArrayList<Watch> watchStore = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addWatches()
    {
            Watch wt = new Watch();
            String name = InputHelper.getInput("Enter name: ");
            String serial = InputHelper.getInput("Enter serial: ");
            String desc = InputHelper.getInput("Enter description: ");
            String color = InputHelper.getInput("Enter Color: ");
            String price = InputHelper.getInput("Enter price: ");
            String weight = InputHelper.getInput("Enter weight: ");

            double pr = Double.parseDouble(price);
            double wg = Double.parseDouble(weight);
            long sr = Long.parseLong(serial);

            wt.addWatch(name, sr, desc, color, pr, wg); // this is a method inside Watch class that is responsible for adding watch information
            watchStore.add(wt);
    }

    public void viewWatch(){
        for (int i = 0; i<watchStore.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(watchStore.get(i));
        }

    }

    public Watch findWatchBySerialNumber(long serial) {
        for(Watch w : watchStore) {
            if(w.getSerial() == serial) {
                System.out.print("found");
                return w;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("not found");
        return null;
    }

    public void deleteWatch(){
        //the code will follow
    }

    public void averageWatch(){
        //the code will follow
    }

}
```

The main menu where you show the catalogue is screwed up. You have 3 case statements in the code and 5 options in the UI. There is no 1-1 correspondance here.

Also, you have to add a new entry into that catalogue which allows the users to exit the application.

Regarding review of your code for performance, as someone pointed out, please go to codereview.stackexchange.com.